# Perl: How to delete files, folders and subdirectories using "rm"?

Tags: perl

I am trying to delete files and folders using my perl script. I'm using the "rm -rf $file" command to delete the file but its not doing anything. 
However, when i try the same command on the cmd line it works and deletes files just fine. 
Attached is the code snippet. Any help is appreciated.

```
for each $f (@files)
{
       system "rm -rf $f";
}
```

I tried this on a couple of machines and its the same problem. However, i tried using other system commands such as mkdir, tar etc and it works just fine.
I have also tried unlinking but the same problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried running this in the debugger?

Comment: Why do you want to use `system` to delete files?

Comment: Why not use `remove_tree` from [File::Path](https://www.metacpan.org/module/File::Path)?

Comment: @Jim, Nope. I'm new to Perl and I will give this a shot.

Comment: At the very least, protect yourself from malicious filenames with `system rm => -rf => $_`. It's just as easy as what you have. Take it as the natural default and only use the other kind of invocation when you have a specific reason to use it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `for` or `foreach`, but there is no `for each`. I've run the code, once I fixed this, the files were deleted.

Using `use strict;` would have found this, because 'each' would have shown up as a bare word.

Here is the code that I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = qw( a.txt b.txt c.txt );

for my $f (@files)
{
   system "rm -rf $f";
}
```

This successfully removed `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`, so I guarantee that it is working code.

Use the perl debugger to inspect @files, and check the permissions on all files that you're trying to delete.

Comment: Actually, [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) is a Perl function.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Not in that situation it's not. `for each $f (@files) { ... }` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Barton Sorry my mistake on the code, it was a typo. I am using foreach in my code but the problem persists. To add to that, it was working just fine last afternoon but since then I made various changes to my code but this little bit is causing problems and I'm still not able to figure out why.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake. I dint specify the whole path to the file while deleting and I was just passing the filename. I fixed it and its working just fine. Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

```
use File::Path;
rmtree('folder_path');  #rmtree('/tmp/test');
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are only files and not folders in your `@files` array then you can also use the `unlink` command which deletes files. This is probably safer than using `rm -rf`. If the element `/` somehow gets into your array then you might end up with a broken Linux with `rm -rf`. [Unlink on perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html).

```
unlink @files;
```

Comment: I have files and folders that need to be deleted and hence I was using rm -rf. But unlink should work just fine on both files and folders right?